# Can you use both dropshadow and innershadow in JavaFX CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, shadow

I would like to have an innershadow AND a boxshadow on the same button using JavaFX CSS. Except all I tried only displays one of the two.

I tried this but only the first one is displayed:

```
-fx-effect:
     innershadow(three-pass-box, rgb(255,255,255),1,0,0,1),
     dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgb(0,0,0),5,0,0,5);
```

Or this but only the last one is displayed:

```
-fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box, rgb(255,255,255),1,0,0,1),
-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgb(0,0,0),5,0,0,5);
```

Are the two mutually exclusive? I did not find any answer on the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS in JavaFX is simply another way of setting properties of nodes. And if you look at the [`Node.effect`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#effectProperty) property, which is the property that `--fx-effect` targets, you'll see it is a simple object property. In other words, a node can only have one effect at any given time. Setting an effect will replace the old one. That's what is happening in your second attempt. I'm actually surprised your first attempt didn't result in a parse error; my guess is that the parser decided it's "done" parsing the effect after the closing parenthesis defining the inner shadow, and then just skips to after the semicolon.

That said, if you look at the implementations of `Effect`, many of them have an `input` property (e.g., [`DropShadow.input`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/DropShadow.html#inputProperty())). That property lets you "layer" effects. You could have a `DropShadow` with an `InnerShadow` as its `input`, then set the `DropShadow` as the effect of the button (or vice versa).

Unfortunately, according to the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect), there's no way to set the `input` of an effect via CSS. That means you'll have to do it in code (or FXML).

For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DropShadow effect = new DropShadow();
        effect.setInput(new InnerShadow());

        Button button = new Button("Test");
        button.setEffect(effect);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 175));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of running example code]

---

For completeness, here's the same scene graph defined in FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <Button text="Test">
    <effect>
      <DropShadow>
        <input>
          <InnerShadow />
        </input>
      </DropShadow>
    </effect>
  </Button>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment and for your time! It solves my problem, although I am still wondering whether the complexity (i.e. defining style effects in different files) is worth it. But that's another problem!

Comment: I suppose one thing you could try, is to put the button in another layout that can't shrink smaller or grow larger than the button. Then put the inner shadow on the button and the drop shadow on the layout. Since it's now two different nodes, both effects can be set via CSS. But I don't know how well that will work.